# Problems with starting windows service on windows xp SP3

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I'm currently facing a problem which I can not resolve and I really don't know what to do anymore.

When I'm trying to start the service I receive the message: "The service is started but again also stopped, this because that some of the services will stop if they have nothing to do, for example the performance logs and the alerts service".

I've looked into the Windows Logs but nothing is written there which could describe why my service is all the time stopping. I've also tried to fire the windows service via the command prompt which gives me the message: "The service is not started, but the service didn't return any faults.".

I've tried to remove all keys which references to my service, which didn't resolve the issue.

I've searched on google (maybe not good enough) to find an answer but I didn't found any. I did found some websites which describes what I could do, but all of these suggestions didn't work.

This is kinda **** because I do not know where to look. I do not have any error message, i do not have any id which i can use to search on. I really don't know where to start and I hope you guys can help me on this one.

**Detailed explanation about the windows service**

**OS:** Windows XP SP3

**.Net Framework:** .Net 4.0 Client Profile

**Language:** C#

**Development environment:** Visual Studio 2010 Professional (but Visual Studio 2012 RC is installed)

**Communications:** WCF (Named Pipes), WCF (BasicHTTPBinding)

*Named Pipes:*

I have chosen for this solution because I wanted to communicate from a windows service to a windows form application. It worked now for quite some time but suddenly my windows service shuts it self down and I couldn't restart it anymore.

There are two named pipes services implemented: An event service which will send any notification to the windows form application and an management service which gives my windows form application the possibility to maintain my windows service.

*BasicHTTPBinding:*

The basic http binding makes the connection to a central server. This connection is then used for streaming information from the client to the server.

I do not know which additional information you will need, but if you guys need something then I'll try to give it as detailed as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the issue and really it is a stupid one. Windows XP will not throw any error or does not report to you that the book where all logs are stored is full!!! After cleaning the log my service started perfectly and keeps running. How stupid! :)